# Обновление/генерация ключей RSA

Tags: криптография, шифрование, rsa

Доброе время суток. Прошу помочь разобраться с ключами RSA (как я понял). Пришел на новое место работы стажером. Дали задание обновить программу, где используется шифрование. Решил заодно, как я понял, обновить ключи или что-то типа того на новые. Не могу понять как это сделать.

Вот кусок кода где указан ключ:

```
STATIC BYTE PublicKey[4096] = "\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\xA4\x00\x00\x52\x53\x41\x32\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\xB5\xB4\xDC\x55\xFE............";
```

Вот функция, где используется ключ:

```
pCryptImportKey(CryptoProvider, PublicKey, sizeof(PublicKey), 0, 0, &RsaPublicKey);
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как обновить переменную `PublicKey` на свое значение. Возможно даже в таком же формате (`\x02\xA4` и т.д.). Я так понял это ключ RSA, но не могу допереть как обновить ключ на свой.

Comment: `\x07` - это шестнадцатеричные (hex) представления кодов символов. Что именно вам непонятно? У вас есть бинарный файл с ключом и вы не знаете, как его в такое текстовое представление перевести или в чём вопрос?

Comment: Если я например введу ключ \x07\xA4\x08 и тд. Просто рандомные символы, то ключ будет работать? Я просто перевел текущий ключ в символы, увидел там три символа рядом "RSA". Я и подумал, что может как-то специально надо генерировать, чтобы эти символы были, без них не заработает. Никогда не сталкивался с RSA до этого момента

Comment: Да-да, сделайте именно так, как собираетесь. И сразу увольняйтесь. Пусть умники, которые допустили до обновления критически значимых параметров приложения необученного стажера, свихнут себе мозг, пытаясь понять, почему работать перестало.

Comment: @СеменАлександрович Так почитайте википедию хотя бы или что там про ключи. Ключи нужно генерить специальными программами.

Comment: Я понял, что специальными программами. Я имею ввиду, что если я сгенерирую ключ, переведу эту в такую hex запись, то все ок будет?

Comment: @СеменАлександрович Ну по идее да - нужно сгенерить и перевести в такой вот текстовый вид, хотя я тоже могу ошибаться )

Comment: @CrazyElf чтобы сгененировать публичный ключ, нужно для начала получить приватный. А это один из важнейших элементов безопасности. В нормальных организациях к нему пускают только под подпись и только доверенных работников.

Comment: @PakUula Да, ситуация выглядит странновато )  Ну, разве что тут шифрование чисто для проформы используется.

Comment: Не можете подсказать сервисы или программы, которые генерят RSA ключ,. Было бы не плохо, если сразу в hex виде)

Comment: Зачем вам сервисы? Просто сгенерите рандом функцией из той-же библиотеки bcrypt.dll и всё. Если RSA, то это асимметричное шифрование, поэтому используйте функции с суффиксом `..KeyPair`. Здесь есть пример: https://www.stackfinder.ru/questions/58419870/how-to-use-bcrypt-for-rsa-asymmetric-encryption

Comment: В данной программе почему-то ключи одинаковые -_-

PrivateKey[4096] = "\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\xA4\x00\x00\x52\x53\x41\x32\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\xB5\xB4\xDC\x55\xFE\x6B\xC0\x05\x65\xD1\xD0\x07\x5F\xDF\xFA

PublicKey[4096] = "\x07\x02\x00\x00\x00\xA4\x00\x00\x52\x53\x41\x32\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\xB5\xB4\xDC\x55\xFE\x6B\xC0\x05\x65\xD1\xD0\x07\x5F\xDF\xFA

Answer (score 3):

То, что вы нам показали - это приватный ключ. Он закодирован как структура данных [`PUBLICKEYSTRUC` (aka `BLOBHEADER`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-publickeystruc)

Первый байт 0x07 означает *The key is a public/private key pair.*  Вызов `CryptImportKey(CryptoProvider, PublicKey, sizeof(PublicKey), 0, 0, &RsaPublicKey);` генерирует из приватного ключа публичный и сохранаяет его в переменную `RsaPublicKey`

Вам нужно точно выяснить задачу. Нельзя просто так брать и обновлять приватные ключи, от этого посыпятся все зависимости, которые завязаны на сертификаты и публичный ключ.

Но если вам интересно, то делается это так.

Функцией [`CryptGenKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenkey) генерируете приватный ключ для алгоритма [`CALG_RSA_KEYX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/base-provider-algorithms). Параметр `dwFlags` должен быть `CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | (4096 << 16)` - длина ключа передаётся как верхние 16 бит параметра `dwFlags`.

*Насчет длины 4096 я усомнился. Посчитайте, сколько байтов в строке `PublicKey` и вычтите 8 байтов заголовка, это будет длина ключа в байтах. Умножте получившееся число на 8 - будет длина в битах.*

Откуда я узнал, что идентификатор `CALG_RSA_KEYX`. Это байты 4-8 в вашем приватном ключе: `\x00\xA4\x00\x00\` или `0x0000a400` в little-endian формате.

Затем функцией [`CryptExportKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptexportkey) вы экспортируете сгененированный ключ в бинарный формат:

- Параметр `hExpKey` равен 0, так как в вашем примере ключ импортируется без расшифровки.
- Параметр `dwBlobType` равен `PRIVATEKEYBLOB`
- Параметр `dwFlags` равен 0

Если всё пройдёт хорошо, в памяти по указателю `pbData` будет лежать сгенерированный ключ, а в параметре `pdwDataLen` будет длина ключа. Вам достаточно распечатать его в шестнадцатиричном формате `\x00` и готово. Можно подставить сгененированную строку вместо `STATIC BYTE PublicKey[4096]`

PS. Размер ключа `BYTE[4096]` - это какая-то феерическая ... выдумка. Размер ключа 4096 БИТ, то есть 512 байт, плюс структура `BLOBHEADER` рамером 8 байт. Итого 520 байт. Да ещё хранение в строковом виде...

Я впечатлён.

Comment: Просмотрите пожалуйста мое решение